# What is the native resolution?

Tags: half-minute-hero-the-second-coming

The game features pixelated art and font, but the pixels are distorted at some common resolutions. What is the native resolution of the game?

Answer (score 1):

The native resolution is 480×270. This means playing at these resolutions will give you perfect pixels:

```
Factor   Resolution   Best for
  ×1     480 ×  270   
  ×2     960 ×  540   1366×768 "HD ready" monitors & windowed mode
  ×3    1440 ×  810   1440×1050 monitors
  ×4    1920 × 1080   1920×1080 "full HD" monitors (native!)
  ×5    2400 × 1350   2048×1152 "2k" monitors
  ×6    2880 × 1620   
  ×7    3360 × 1890   
  ×8    3840 × 2160   4096×2304 "4k" monitors
           (etc.)
```

Unless you have a 1080p monitor and want to go fullscreen or you can stand uneven looking text, you are probably going to be better served by windowed mode.

Comment: It is funny how some people like to answer their own questions. I have done that once, it was weird. It was like talking to a different person.

Comment: @Scribblenautical http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: ♦ that was awesome. How long did you spend searching for the link? xD

Comment: You were an intern at google? wow. Impressive. So you probably know more about me than anyone else... 0.0

Comment: @Scribblenautical It's linked right at the bottom of   http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask